# Python: Can scipy.optimize,bisection use a function f that returns multiple values?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, bisection, multiple-return-values

Suppose I have a function, f, that returns multiple values.

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1, 2 * x
```

Scipy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html) tells me that f must be a function that returns a number. I take it that my given function f isn't compatible for scipy.optimize.bisection, but is it possible to perform the bisection method on just one of the return values of f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that calls your function `f` and extracts the second return value:

```py
from scipy.optimize import bisect

def f(x):
    return x + 1, 2 * x

bisect(lambda x: f(x)[1], -1, 1)
```